# How to pass secrets retrieved from Key Vault to ARM template deployment during a pipeline run?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

Within a pipeline run, we are attempting to use the retrieved key vault secret in an ARM template deployment. The secret value is a SAS URL.

We first retrieved all secrets using the AzureKeyVault@2 task

```
  - task: AzureKeyVault@2
    displayName: 'Retrieve all secrets necessary for install'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'SUBSCRIPTION'
      KeyVaultName: 'KEYVAULT'
      SecretsFilter: 'SECRET'
      RunAsPreJob: false
```

We have two files in our repo: a Bicep template and a parameters JSON file, since .bicepparam 's don't support key vault references. The parameters file is already referencing the secret we need, but the template doesn't seem to be using it during deployment. The pipeline's service principal has the Key Vault Secrets User role on the key vault's scope.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "SECRET_PARAM": {
        "reference": {
            "keyVault": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTION/resourceGroups/RESOURCEGROUP/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/KEYVAULT"
            },
                "secretName": "SECRET"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm guessing I should be passing the retrieved secret value from the pipeline task to the deployment task but I'm not sure how to do that when I'm already referencing a params file.

Let me know if any additional detail is needed. I'd appreciate any guidance you all can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mix two different approaches for parameters.

**1. Reference to AKV from the parameters file.**

In this case, you do not need to use `AzureKeyVault@2`. Check this manual: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/key-vault-parameter?tabs=azure-cli

**2. Update parameters during deployment**

In this case, you do not need a secret reference in the parameter file. Just store it as a usual value. Then you may update it in the `AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3` task.

As an example:

The parameter (just with some default value)

```
"parameters": {
        "SECRET_PARAM": {
           "value": "SECRET"
        }
    }
```

The ARM task

```
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
  inputs:
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'MY_CONNECTION'
    subscriptionId: 'MY_ID'
    resourceGroupName: 'MY_RG'
    location: 'West Europe'
    csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/my_template_or_bicep_file'
    csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/mt_parameters_file'
    overrideParameters: '-SECRET_PARAM "$(SECRET)"'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not pass out the secret cross. you can use inner refer.
using **existing** resource and the use **getSecret('xxx')**.  below is the offical example:

```
param sqlServerName string
param adminLogin string

param subscriptionId string
param kvResourceGroup string
param kvName string

resource kv 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-02-01' existing = {
  name: kvName
  scope: resourceGroup(subscriptionId, kvResourceGroup )
}

module sql './sql.bicep' = {
  name: 'deploySQL'
  params: {
    sqlServerName: sqlServerName
    adminLogin: adminLogin
    adminPassword: kv.getSecret('vmAdminPassword')
  }
}
```

Here is the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/key-vault-parameter?tabs=azure-cli)

Comment: our key vault's network settings is set up to only allow access to a limited set of IP's. is there a way to get the IP of the resource as it's getting deployed so that we can add that IP to the allow-list?

Comment: @yamh, have you ever tried using bicep output, such as "output ips array = symbolicname.properties.networkAcls.ipRules" in getting the ip rules for keyVault ?